# How to calculate difference between columns in different data frames with similar pattern in column names?

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to compute the difference between columns in two data frames. The data frames have a different total number of columns and the column names between the data frames have a similar pattern. I would like to compute the difference between similarly named columns.

I would appreciate some hints on how to start thinking about executing this in R or some example code.

Here is a sample of what the data frames look like:

DF1

```
w_H_11_XA    w_H_13_XA    w_H_16_XA    w_13_03_XA    w_13_12_XA
10           12          1                8           12
11           11          8                6           19
```

DF2

```
w_H_11_BA    w_H_16_BA     w_13_12_BA
8            1            10
9            4            9
```

So here both data sets have columns w_H_11*, w_H_16*, and w_13_12* 'in common', meaning they have similar patterns in the column names. I would like to produce a data set which takes the difference between the similarly matched columns only. Like so:

```
w_H_11    w_H_16    w_13_12
2          0         2
2          4         10
```

I have thought about merging the data frames and arranging the columns in order by name; however, I am not sure how to automate computing the difference. The actual data set has a few hundred columns.

Would appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the difference between the two names are just the last character, then we could use `adist`

```
 a = which(adist(names(DF1),names(DF2))==1,T) 
 result = DF1[,a[,1]]-DF2[,a[,2]]
 setNames(result,sub("_[A-Z]$",'',names(result)))
  w_H_11 w_H_16 w_13_12
1      2      0       2
2      2      4      10
```

with the updated table, it seems we delete all the letters to the end thus you could do:

`a = which(do.call(adist,lapply(list(names(DF1),names(DF2)),sub,pat="_[^_]*$",rep=""))==0,T)` and the rest remains

Comment: So the only difference between the column names is actually the last two letters (I made the change in my example) and also the fact that there are some columns in one data set that are not in the other.

Comment: thank you! This worked and did not give me the same issue (in terms of similarity) that using grep did!

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to remove the suffix part from the column names, then do the `intersect` and use that to subset the columns of the data.frame and get the diffference

```
nm1 <- sub("_[A-Z]$", "", names(DF1))
nm2 <- sub("_[A-Z]$", "", names(DF2))
nm3 <- intersect(nm1, nm2)
nm4 <- paste(nm3, collapse="|")
out <- DF1[grep(nm4, names(DF1))] - DF2[grep(nm4, names(DF2))]
names(out) <- sub("_[A-Z]$", "", names(out))
out
#  w_H_11 w_H_16 w_13_12
#1      2      0       2
#2      2      4      10
```

#### data

```
DF1 <- structure(list(w_H_11_A = 10:11, w_H_13_A = 12:11, w_H_16_A = c(1L, 
8L), w_13_03_A = c(8L, 6L), w_13_12_A = c(12L, 19L)), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))

DF2 <- structure(list(w_H_11_B = 8:9, w_H_16_B = c(1L, 4L), 
    w_13_12_B = 10:9), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: Thanks so much - I tried this and got all the way to the last step where the subtraction is performed. However, it seems like using grep on DF1 ends up identifying an extra two columns.
What I mean is the number of columns of intersect(nm1, nm2) is 1682, but when I subset DF1 with grep I get 1684 columns. So it seems like there are a couple of columns that are similar enough in DF1 that grep is picking them up.
When I use fixed = TRUE in grep, I get 0 columns...

Comment: @AnnaY.  It is based on your example.  Regarding other columnss, it was not mentioned in the post